# SystemTray In Elementary OS Doesn't Work

Tags: java, linux, scala, awt

I'm trying to run an application which uses the `java.awt.SystemTray` class on Elementary OS, a Linux Distribution. Unfortunately, `SystemTray` isn't supported on Elementary OS (`SystemTray.isSupported()` returns `false`).

Is there some way to get the system tray working without losing portability?

Comment: This question has been asked over here with some responses: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1706/system-tray-icons-for-java-and-nodewebkit-applications